# Como utilizar o @ em SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql-server

Preciso recuperar a quantidade de produto com preço entre 0 e 10. Existe em erro na variavel @W_NUM do comando select.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DECLARE @W_P1 int;
DECLARE @W_P2 int;
DECLARE @W_NUM int;
set @W_P1=0;
SET @W_P2=10;
SET @W_NUM=0;

BEGIN 
WHILE (@W_P2<300)
SELECT COUNT(P_CODE)INTO @W_NUM FROM PRODUCTT WHERE P_PRICE>@W_P1 AND P_PRICE<@W_P2;
PRINT('EXISTEM'+@W_NUM+'PRODUTOS COM O PRECO ENTRE'+@W_P1+' E '+@W_P2)
@W_P1=@W_P1+1;
@W_P2=@W_P2+50;
END
COMMIT
```

Comment: qual erro você recebe?

Comment: Verifique também se a sua tabela chama mesmo `PRODUCTT` com 2 `T`

Comment: NO ENCRIMENTO @W_P1=@W_P1+1;
@W_P2=@W_P2+50;

Comment: Mas qual a mensagem/codigo de erro?

Comment: @OrlandoCawende http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experimente

```
-- código #1 v2
DECLARE @W_P1 int;
DECLARE @W_P2 int;
DECLARE @W_NUM int;
set @W_P1= 0;
set @W_P2= 10;
set @W_NUM= 0;

WHILE (@W_P2 < 300)
  BEGIN
  SET @W_NUM= (SELECT COUNT(P_CODE) FROM PRODUCTT 
                 WHERE P_PRICE > @W_P1 AND P_PRICE < @W_P2);
  PRINT 'EXISTEM ' + Cast(@W_NUM as varchar(10)) +
         ' PRODUTOS COM O PREÇO ENTRE ' + Cast(@W_P1 as varchar(10)) +
         ' E ' + Cast(@W_P2 as varchar(10));
  --
  set @W_P1= @W_P1 + 1;
  set @W_P2= @W_P2 + 50;
  END;
```

Comment: Obrigado funcionou muito bem. No entanto gostava de saber se existe uma forma de empressao sem utilizar esta e porque converter em varchar   SELECT 'EXISTEM ' + Cast(@W_NUM as varchar(10)) +
         ' PRODUTOS COM O PREÇO ENTRE ' + Cast(@W_P1 as varchar(10)) +
         ' E ' + Cast(@W_P2 as varchar(10))

Comment: @OrlandoCawende, como a mensagem é uma expressão string, as variáveis que não são do tipo string (char, varchar etc) devem ser previamente convertidas para string. Há casos em que é gerado conversão implícita, pelo próprio SQL Server, mas, para evitar erros, é melhor implementar a conversão.

Comment: Obrigado. poderia ajudar neste caso tenho uma tabela no qual quando a quantidade em stock(P_QOH) for inferior ou igual   a quantidade minima(P_MIN) deve colocar em P_REORDER=1 caso contrario 
P_REORDER=0 consegui faze-lo em Oracle mais preciso ele em sql server 2012 como fazar isto. 


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_PRODUCTT_REORDER
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF P_QOH ,P_MIN ON PRODUCTT
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF:NEW.P_QOH<=NEW.P_MIN THEN
 :NEW.P_REORDER:=1;
 ELSE
 :NEW.P_REORDER:=0;
END IF;
END;
/

Comment: @OrlandoCawende, a respeito dessa nova solicitação, sugiro que crie um novo tópico, onde poderá formatar adequadamente o código e descrever o que necessita.

Comment: Nao tenho mais permissão de fazer perguntas

Answer (score 3):

Tente fazer:

```
SELECT @W_NUM = COUNT(P_CODE) FROM PRODUCTT WHERE P_PRICE>@W_P1 AND P_PRICE<@W_P2;
```

Comment: NESTE ENCREMENTO @W_P1=@W_P1+1;
@W_P2=@W_P2+50;

Comment: o que tem o incremento?